# How to extract only the contents enclosed in () to an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I've text like `abcd(123.45), efgh ijk(abcd), lmno(12kdd)`, I want to extract the contents enclosed within the `()` to array like `["123.45", "abcd", "12kdd"]`.

I wrote an RegEx to solve this but it is not giving the correct results. How to solve this issue.

My RegEx is as follows

```
[^\(\)]+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
var text = "abcd(123.45), efgh ijk(abcd), lmno(12kdd)";
var results = text.match(/[^\(]+?(?=\))/gi);
```

Here I'm using the [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) concept of Regular Expression.

It takes all the character other than `(` which are followed by a `)` but excluding the `)` character.